# Primefaces datatable header alignment

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with primefaces datatable. As you can see there is an alignment problem with columns border and headers. Is this a primefaces bug or there is something wrong with my datatable? By the way datatable has dynamic columns. [image: datatable]

```
<p:dataTable     scrollable="true" scrollWidth="100%" editable="true" editMode="cell"   
var="invoiceLine" value="#{myController.invoiceLines}"                          
                         selection="#{myController.selectedInvoiceLine}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{invoiceLine.uuid}"
                         >
<p:columns value="#{myController.columns}" var="column"
                           styleClass="ui-editable-column" width="50"
                           columnIndexVar="colIndex">

//some stuff
</p:columns>         

            </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: which primeface version you are using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do one trick,

```
Remove scrollable = true
```

and create new style class like,

```
.ui-datatable-hor-scroll .ui-datatable-tablewrapper,.scrolling-div .ui-datatable-tablewrapper{
     overflow: auto;
     width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 5px;}
```

apply `styleClass` to `p:datatable` like `styleClass="ui-datatable-hor-scroll"`

Comment: I have tried ur answer, but (1) the scrolling does not work (2) the style class is only applied to the `div` not to the `table`. (PF 3,5 and 4.0-SNAPSHOT on IE8)

Comment: Like this the header will not be visible if you scroll down

Answer (score 6):

The problem is still present in 6.2.
Another solution, with width set in style attribute, is to replace

```
<p:column style="width:100px">
```

with

```
<p:column style="width:calc(100px)">
```

[MDN-calc() description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: Remarkable... Any explanation why these two have a different behaviour?  (actually curious ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who has this problem - Primfaces scrollable continues to have issues. I am on 5.1 and it isn't working.

Just use a normal datatable and then use CSS3 to get the scrolling to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/xuvsncr2/170/

Of course don't use table, thead, tr etc. for targeting elements. Instead use css classes so that you get the right datatable.

The tricky part is that in order to set the size of the scroll pane, you need to target the div directly surrounding the table. You can see how I did this below

Heres more on the flexbox for css3: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Heres an example of the css I used for primefaces. I just wrapped my datatable with a `<div class="myCompanyScrollable thirtyEM">`

```
.thirtyEM .ui-datatable-tablewrapper{
height: 30em;
}
.myCompanyScrollable table {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.myCompanyScrollable table thead {
    /* head takes the height it requires, 
    and it's not scaled when table is resized */
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: calc(100% - 1.05em);
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.myCompanyScrollable table tbody {
    /* body takes all the remaining available space */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.myCompanyScrollable table tbody tr {
    width: 100%;
}
.myCompanyScrollable table tbody tr {
    display: table;
     width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
/* decorations */
.myCompanyScrollable {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
.myCompanyScrollable table {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.myCompanyScrollable table td, .myCompanyScrollable table th {
    padding: 0.3em;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.myCompanyScrollable table th {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is ***solved*** in primefaces latest version ( **7.0** )

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces

Comment: no it's not, unless they introduced a regression bug I'm on 10 and it's still happening

Comment: I can also report that this bug still exists. Making the datatable "scrollable" with pure CSS seems to be the best option for now, still.

Answer (score -1):

Try below jquery code

```
$('.datatableclassname').find(('div.ui-datatable-scrollable-header ')+'div.ui-dt-c').each(function(index) {
            var cur_obj = $(this);
            var column_num = parseInt(index+1);
            $('.datatableclassname div.ui-datatable-scrollable-body tr > td:nth-child('+column_num+') > div.ui-dt-c').css('width',cur_obj.width()+'px');
        });
```

Comment: I dont understand the relation between jquery and primefaces. I dont use jquery.

Comment: @TurgutDsfadfa JSF implementation includes jquery library. You have it by default. What I don't understand is why this table became so complex to _render_ and why it requires this _complex patch_ to do it correctly... Can you please add some code to clarify which are the specificities with this datatable? Regards,

Comment: @RodmarConde Here is my columns. I think there is a problem with my columns. By the way there is nothing related to style at my datatable.  <p:columns styleClass="ui-editable-column" width="50" ..>

Comment: Does the datatable's scrollable property is true?

Comment: What happens if you remove **width="50"** ? You can achieve the columns width in another way. Regards,

Comment: This is a very bad use of Javascript. The CSS work around above is a far better idea. With your JQuery workaround, what happens to the table if I decide to change the borders or padding?